# MUI DatePicker disbalePast functionality need to use with custome datepicker bordercolour in specific condition

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, material-ui, datepicker, disable

I used MUI V5 DatePicker for the form field so there are two types which are the Create part and the Edit part. when working with edit if there DatePicker date is past date then the DatePicker border color will show as red colour it is perfectly okay. because when [CREATE] there should be that validation but when [EDIT] I still need that disablePast functionality but need to remove that Red Color border from it. Is this scenario is possible thing? if possible give some guides for that my sample code is attached below.

````
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
                      <DemoContainer sx={{ paddingTop: 0 }} components={['DatePicker']}>
                        <DatePicker
                          disablePast
                          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
                          value={formData.startDate.value}
                          onChange={(newValue) => { onInputHandleForm('startDate', newValue) }
                          }
                          slotProps={{
                            textField: {
                              onBeforeInput: onAnyTextFieldChanged,
                              InputProps: {
                                readOnly: true,
                                style: {
                                  // Check the condition and set the border color accordingly
                                  borderColor: isEditGoal === true ? 'green' : 'yellow' //not working
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }}

                        />
                      </DemoContainer>
                    </LocalizationProvider> ```
````